# How to get WebSocket close code from Akka HTTP?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

We are using Akka HTTP to handle our web socket connections using the akka streams API. We are using a Flow that pipes the incoming messages to a "connection actor". A snippet of the code is below:

```
val connection = system.actorOf(ConnectionActor.props())

val in = Flow[Message]
  .to(Sink.actorRef[Message](connection, WebSocketClosed))

val out = Source
  .actorRef[Message](500, OverflowStrategy.fail)
  .mapMaterializedValue(ws => connection ! WebSocketOpened(ws))

Flow.fromSinkAndSource(in, out)
```

When the web socket is closed, the connection actor is sent the "WebSocketClose" message and we clean up internal resources. We now have the requirement to know what the reason for closing the connection was according to the standard [WebSocket CloseEvent codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CloseEvent).

Is there a way to get the close code from Akka HTTP and send it on to the connection actor so it can take the appropriate action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, this is not presently possible in Akka HTTP.  See the following GitHub issue:

https://github.com/akka/akka-http/issues/2458

It looks as though this will need to be addressed before this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to handle client (browser) error code in an `akka-http 10.2.6` server.

My use case was to pipe incoming messages to a `Sink` created by `ActorSink.actorRef[T]()`. When creating the sink, 2 callbacks `onCompleteMessage`  `onFailureMessage` can be set to converts normal WebSocket close (code=1000) or error to our custom message types.

I suppose that client close/error maps to Flow complete/failure, that means other sinks should be able to handle close/error in a similar way.

[my code](https://github.com/jokester/fullstack-playground/blob/f80dcdc291a1408a60c473c1654e1f24bf4bcfb3/server-scala/stateless-akka-http/src/main/scala/io/jokester/fullstack_playground/stateless_akka_http/routes/ActorBasedRoutes.scala#L135-L146)
`